# Adding new PHP modules

Tags: php, module, imap

I am having problems with my IMAP PHP module installation and want to try either installing this module again without recompiling PHP (is this possible?) or at least look at the configuration of all of the PHP modules. After doing some Googling, I am still at a loss as to how to:

1. Install new PHP modules without recompiling PHP, if possible.
2. Configure the installed PHP modules.

I notice that the IMAP module appears on a webpage with `<?php php_info(); ?>` but does NOT appear with `php -i` on the command line.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: if you are using linux, run command "whereis php". This will list the path of php binaries (possible paths being /usr/bin/php /usr/share/bin/php or as compiled). Run php -i with absolute path like "/usr/bin/php -i" for different paths from whereis output and check if php-imap appears in any of them.

Answer (score 3):

Check the ini file(s) referenced in the output of `php -i`. The CLI uses a different php.ini file, and you may need to enable the module in that php.ini.